# one of the dropped column appears when trying to hide index column in r shiny rendered table

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to drop the index column form R shiny rendered table using `rowname=FALSE` in the below part of the code. But somehow the dropped column "schema" still appears in the rendered table. I can't understand where is the problem with the code. Any help is very much appreciated.

Data:

```
schema  gruppe  name    Week    dose    symptome
A         A1    XXX        1    1.2     HA
A         A2    YYY        2    11.2    DI
B         A1    XXX        1    1.2     HA
B         A2    YYY        2    11.2    DI
C         A1    XXX        1    1.2     HA
C         A2    YYY        2    11.2    DI
D         A1    XXX        1    1.2     HA
D         A2    YYY        2    11.2    DI
E         A1    XXX        1    1.2     HA
E         A2    YYY        2    11.2    DI
F         A1    XXX        1    1.2     HA
F         A2    YYY        2    11.2    DI
```

```
 
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  drug <- read.csv("Combined_All_gruppe.csv", fileEncoding="latin1" )
  
  
  filterVars <- c("gruppe", "name", "dose", "schema")
  freezeReactiveValue(input, "gruppe")
  updateSelectizeInput(session, 'gruppe', choices = c("", unique(drug$gruppe)), selected = "", server = TRUE)
  
  filteredData <- reactive({
    tmpDF <- drug
    for(var in filterVars){
      if(isTruthy(input[[var]])){
        filteredTmpDF <- with(tmpDF, tmpDF[get(var) %in% input[[var]],])
        if(nrow(filteredTmpDF) > 0){
          tmpDF <- filteredTmpDF
        }
      }
    }
    tmpDF
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$gruppe, {
    updateSelectizeInput(session, 'name', choices = c("", unique(filteredData()$name)), selected = "", server = TRUE)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$name, {
    updateSelectizeInput(session, 'dose', choices = c("", unique(filteredData()$dose)), selected = "", server = TRUE)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$dose, {
    updateSelectizeInput(session, 'schema', choices = c("", unique(filteredData()$schema)), selected = "", server = TRUE)
  })
  
  

  
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
   hide_columns <- which(names(filteredData()) %in% c("schema", "gruppe","name", "dose", "symptome"))
    datatable(filteredData(), extensions='Buttons', rownames=FALSE,  options=list(columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE,  targets=hide_columns))))
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the `Week` should be printed. The reason for the problem is that `datatable` (DT package) is a wrapper of a Javascript library. And while R counts indices with `1` to `n` as the first index, Javascript uses `0` to `(n-1)`.

Subtract 1 from the column indices and you see only the week column.

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  dataTableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  filteredData <- reactiveVal(
    data.frame(
      schema = letters[1:5], gruppe = LETTERS[1:5], name = paste0("name", 1:5),
      week = 1:5,
      dose = 1:5, symptome = letters[1:5]
    )
  )
  
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    hide_columns <- which(names(filteredData()) %in% c("schema", "gruppe", "name", "dose", "symptome"))-1L
    datatable(filteredData(), extensions='Buttons', rownames=FALSE,  
              options=list(columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE,  targets=hide_columns))))
  })  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi Jan, thank you! I didn't quite get it what the program does here with the letters and paste0. Could you please clarify to the newbee like me..

Comment: I just created a mocked data frame with the same columns as yours. The content of the data frame has no meaning. It is not necessary to show that it works in principle.

Comment: I am still scratching my head to where in my code to implement your code. I have copied complete server.r code. Could you please take a look.

Comment: All you have to do is in the line `hide_columns <- which(...)` from which you subtract 1 (`- 1L` in the code)  to change the 1-based index to a zero-based one. That is the only necessary change that I made. The rest is just to demonstrate that it works.